# PYTHON - Check if cell contains a string from another cell

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a column "Held?" in my pandas dataframe that flags whenever the character in one of the cells "DrpType" is contained in another cell "HeldDrpTypes" from the same row.

I've tried using `where` and `in` but it didn't work:

`df['Held?'] = where(df['DrpType'] in df['HeldDrpTypes'] == True),'Yes','No')`

This is what I want to accomplish:

```py
> print(df)
      DrpType     HeldDrpTypes     Held?    
0       A              B            No
1       B              BC           Yes
2       C              B            No
3       B              BC           Yes
4       A              BC           No
5       C              BC           Yes
```

Any ideas how I can go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a pure pandas way, you can use `df.apply()`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'DrpType': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'C',],
    'HeldDrpTypes':['B', 'BC', 'B', 'BC', 'BC', 'BC']
})

df['Held?'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['DrpType'] in row['HeldDrpTypes'], axis=1)

print(df)
#   DrpType HeldDrpTypes  Held?
# 0       A            B  False
# 1       B           BC   True
# 2       C            B  False
# 3       B           BC   True
# 4       A           BC  False
# 5       C           BC   True
```

If you are a stickler for `Yes`/`No` rather than `True`/`False`, you can use the following, but I'd suggest sticking with the binary `True`/`False` to make it easier to check for truthiness rather than having to parse a string.

```
df['Held?'] = df.apply(
    lambda row: 'Yes' if row['DrpType'] in row['HeldDrpTypes'] else 'No', axis='columns')

print(df)
#   DrpType HeldDrpTypes Held?
# 0       A            B    No
# 1       B           BC   Yes
# 2       C            B    No
# 3       B           BC   Yes
# 4       A           BC    No
# 5       C           BC   Yes
```

Answer (score 2):

I was curious about the timings of both answers, so I tested them out using a bigger dataframe:

```
df = pd.concat([df]*100000, ignore_index=True)

print(df.shape)

(600000, 2)
```

---

## Timings:

**Wen-Bens** answer with `list comprehension:`

```
%%timeit

df['Held'] = ['Yes' if x in y else 'No' for x , y in zip(df.DrpType,df.HeldDrpTypes)]
```

Gives the following:

```
304 ms ± 17.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

---

**Brian Cohans** answer using `.apply`

```
%%timeit

df['Held?'] = df.apply(
    lambda row: 'Yes' if row['DrpType'] in row['HeldDrpTypes'] else 'No', axis='columns')
```

Gives the following:

```
23.2 s ± 1.23 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

So the difference in speed is actually in magnitude of +- 1000 in favor of the `list comprehension`

Comment: That is ridiculous! Though I guess I'm not really shocked that a comprehension, being a native python idiom, working on two series is faster than something built with python lugging around all the contents of the dataframe. It is a bit shocking for a dataframe with literally 2 columns, but I'd hate to think of the time difference with a more complicated dataframe. Thanks for testing the difference. Obviously there's considerations of your actual data size and readability to consider, but I'll certainly have to keep this in mind going forward.

Comment: I ran the numbers myself as well. List comprehension with `Yes`/`No` output: 62ms, numpy method with `True`/`False` output: 456ms. `df.apply()` method with either output: 11.7 s.

Answer (score 1):

You may check

```
l=['Yes' if x in y else 'No' for x , y in zip(df.DrpType,df.HeldDrpTypes)]
l
Out[196]: ['No', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes']


df['Held']=l
```

Or we using the method from `numpy`

```
np.core.chararray.find(df.HeldDrpTypes.values.astype(str),df.DrpType.values.astype(str))!=-1
Out[201]: array([False,  True, False,  True, False,  True])
```

Comment: Wonder about the timings, I think the list comprehension can be over 1000x faster than the `apply` method

Comment: If you're curious, did some timings